# How to move sub-dictionary to another dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am writing a function that takes 2 strings as inputs and would move a section of the dictionary to another.

```
def move(item_to_move, destination):
    # do something....
```

My initial dictionary looks like this.

```
directories = { 
    'beers': {
        'ipa': {
            'stone': {}
        } 
    },

    'wines': {
        'red': {
            'cabernet': {}
        }
    },
    'other' : {}
}
```

I would like to move either a subsection or section of the dictionary to another section. The sections are represented by each key of the path delimited by a '/'. For example, the inputs for my function would be:

```
item_to_move='beers/ipa'
destination='other'

move(directories, item_to_move,destination)
```

The output would be:

```
{ 
    'wines': {
        'red': {
            'cabernet': {}
        },
    },
    'other' :{
        'beers': {
            'ipa': {
                'stone': {}
        }   } 
    },
}
```

NOTE: I am assuming all input paths for items_to_move are valid.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: `pop` can retrive and reomve something.
Then you can attach that object somewhere else in the dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the origin's parent dictionary and the target's dictionary, then update the the target's dictionary with the origin's key and value (removing it from the origin's parent):

```
def move(tree,originPath,targetPath):
    originKey = None
    for originName in originPath.split("/"):
        originParent = originParent[originKey] if originKey else tree
        originKey = originName
    targetDict = tree
    for targetName in targetPath.split("/"):
        targetDict = targetDict[targetName] 
    targetDict.update({originKey:originParent.pop(originKey)})
```

output:

```
directories = { 
    'beers': {
        'ipa': {
            'stone': {}
        } 
    },

    'wines': {
        'red': {
            'cabernet': {}
        }
    },
    'other' : {}
}

move(directories,'beers/ipa','other')
print(directories)

{ 'beers': {},
  'wines': { 'red': {'cabernet': {}} },
  'other': { 'ipa': {'stone':    {}} }
}
```

Comment: This works it's just very difficult to wrap my head around. What happens when the targetPath is nested? For example instead of 'other' we have 'wines/red'?

Comment: It also works because the loop on `targetPath.split("/")` will keep updating the `targetDict ` variable with the lower level key until it reaches the deepest level (i.e. last part of the path).  After the loop you are left with the deepest level sub-dictionary in `targetDict ` which matches the path and is the one you want to update.

Comment: Ahhhh I see now. The fact that each path is valid makes this easier to understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: Indeed this would fail horribly if you gave it paths that are not in the directories tree. But no worse than giving a bad key to any dictionary.